# Firebase get with where clause and order of data returned

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, where-clause

I have below code in my cloud function. Firestore api call is made to retrieve data that matches a certain document id.

```
        await myClinics
          .where(FieldPath.documentId(), "in", ["51","32","23","41"])
          .get()
          .then((snapshots) => {
            snapshots.forEach((doc) => {
              // console.log(doc.data());
              
            });
          });
```

When data is returned, what will be the order of results? will it be of same order as the query (["51","32","23","41"])?
Is there a documentation reference relating to this?

I would like to know which data matches document ID 51 and which data matches document ID 32 etc..

This is more of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documents will be returned in the order in which they occur in the index, not in the order in which you specify the values in the `in` clause.

If you want to execute specific code for document `51`, check the `doc.id` value in your code.